# Does Google's ML Kit allow scanning of inverse barcodes?

Tags: google-mlkit

I'm looking into Google's ML Kit for barcode scanning.  One of the issues I'm having is being able to scan inverse barcodes, which are dark/black barcodes on a light/white background.  I was wondering if anyone knows if this is possible to achieve with ML Kit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support in the ML KIT for inverse barcodes. However your program decides whether it accesses the kit with a file or a snapshot, so you could make a function that simply flips every byte of the picture before sending it.

Comment: It seems MLKit actually does support some inverted barcodes. At least I was able to scan inverted QR Codes with MLKit.